# How do we know that that time traveled by a body and the time we observe are same?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, classical-mechanics

I got the doubt when i was solving this problem. Suppose jack covered a some distance (say)d in time t(observed in his clock) with uniform velocity (<< c --> so no time dilation is observed). Now another guy who is at a large distance from jack, observe jack and measures the time t' (in his own clock).

***How do we know that t'=t?***

In the given problem, emission theory is considered which says that speed of light is dependent on the speed of the source and is relative. so ***t'=T/2 (+-) (some term)***. But we know that speed of light is constant in vacuum so why do we observe that ***t'=T/2*** (same as the first doubt) ?

[image]

Comment: Here I am just asking about the concept, not the answer. I already know the answer but just asking why if speed of light is constant, the time is t' = T/2? How is this question says that i didn't put  any effort (or) not asking a specific concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Newtonian physics $\Delta{t^\prime} = \Delta{t}$ by assumption: all clocks tick at exactly the same rate regardless of any relative motion, and all observers agree on the duration time between any pair of events. In a Newtonian universe, if two events are simultaneous for one observer, they are simultaneous for all observers. It's just an assumed symmetry under Galilean relativity.

The problem doesn't really touch on this particular point. But it is set in a Newtonian universe and is asking us to consider a model in which the speed of light in vacuum is *not* constant for all observers, but instead depends on the relative motion of the source and observer. Under this model, at position I, the light emitted by the star has speed $c - v$, and at position II, it has speed $c + v$.

The time needed for the light to reach the Earth from position I is $t_I = \frac{\ell}{c - v}$. From that position, it takes time $T/2$ for the star to move to position II. From position II, the time needed for the light to reach the Earth is $t_{II} = \frac{\ell}{c - v}$.

At the moment observers on the Earth see the star at position I, it has already been moving for a time $T/2$ toward position II, so that from that moment it will reach position II in a time $T/2 - t_{I}$. Add to this the duration of time needed for the light to reach the earth from position II ($t_{II}$) and after some algebra you will get the answer to part (a). You get the answer to part (b) in a similar way, and the answer to part (c) you can get by inspection.

The point of the question is that in a universe containing a very huge number of binary systems, if Newtonian physics is the correct model, why do we not ever see the situation described by this problem? (Because Newtonian physics is not the correct model.)

Comment: Here why are we just considering the speed of light at only position I and II? even though the entire path has a different distances from earth and velocity component along the line joining earth and some position in between I and II?

Comment: I think you're pointing out that the star is emitting light all along its path, and not just at positions I and II, and that all along its path the distance from the Earth is continuously changing. Yes, that's true. But we are considering the speed of light only at positions I and II in order to simplify the problem. Imagine instead of a star that we are looking at a satellite with an identical orbit that sends a flash of light toward the Earth at position I and again at position II. At all other positions, the satellite does not send any signal.